# Implementing a custom header bar for chromiumembedded

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, webview, chromium, chromium-embedded

I have built the chromiumembedded cefsimple project successfully with visual studio. I need to know whether I could implement a custom header bar instead of below.

[image]

Eg: with a separate favicon and Title being set as a custom manner .. etc.

Your kind help is really appreciated.

Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

If you are based on CefSimple, take a look at simple_handler_win.cpp.  In SimpleHandler::OnTitleChange(), you can set the window title to what you want, instead of what CefSimple wants by changing the SetWindowText() call.  This will appear shortly after launch, replacing the app name.

To change the app icons, just replace the icons in the projects cefsimple.rc.

If you want to change them dynamically, that will be a bit more work.